# Can unsigned int replace Pointers in C

Tags: c

As range of "unsigned int" is equal to range of " int *" or any pointer since both take 4Bytes in 64bit platform. Can pointer in C can be replaced by unsigned int ??

Comment: On a 64-bit platform where pointers are 64 bits (i.e. 8 bytes)? No. On any other platform? No.

Comment: As far as I know both take 8 bytes on 64 bit and 4 bytes on 32 bit machines.

Comment: unsigned int's don't point to anything.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such guarantee for `unsigned int`. A special type [`uintptr_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) was introduced in C99 to hold a pointer, regardless of the platform. You need to include `<stdint.h>` header to use this type.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. Pointers may be *eight* bytes, not four, on a 64-bit platform! You can sometimes get away with casting between `long long` and a 64-bit pointer, but even that is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

You cant even be sure that `int` is 4 Bytes in 64Bit arch! as the type limits are absolutly implementation and enviroment defined. The standard only gives a limitation of which value has to have at least which range. Thats all. `int` could even be 8 Bytes on 64 Bit it could be 10 Bytes, or it could be 13 Bytes or it could be What ever the enviroment wants its size to have. So ofcourse you can replace it. But it could end in invalid alignments or cause data loss.
As each assignement of types of different size can have.
But at least you can assign a pointer value to an `int` value. But also this is the only conversion from value type to pointer type which is valid by ISO/IEC9899.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Slightly longer answer: there's no guarantee that `unsigned int` will be able to hold a valid pointer value for a given platform (several people have already pointed out that 64-bit platforms will likely have address values that fall outside of the range of `unsigned int`).  This is further complicated by the fact that pointers to different types may have different sizes and representations.

Pointers don't just encode an address value; they also encode a *type*.  This matters for pointer arithmetic and array subscripting.  For example, assume the declarations:

```
char *cp = 0x4000;
int  *ip = 0x4000;
float (*dap)[10] = 0x4000;
```

All three pointers (`cp`, `ip`, `dap`) start out with the same value: `0x4000`.  However, adding 1 to each pointer will give different results.  Assuming 32-bit `int` and `float` types, we'd get:

```
cp + 1  == 0x4001
ip + 1  == 0x4004;
dap + 1 == 0x4028;
```

Adding 1 to `cp` gives us the address of the next `char` object (0x4001), adding 1 to `ip` gives us the address of the next `int` object (0x4004), and adding 1 to `dap` gives us the address of the next 10-element array of `float` object (0x4028).  This allows us to use the `[]` operator on each pointer: we can write `cp[i]` and `ip[i]` and get the result we expect (the `i`'th element following the pointer).  If you typed all those pointers as `unsigned int`, however, you wouldn't be able to use the subscript operator, and adding 1 to them would only give you the next byte address, not necessarily the address of the next object.